# Dictionary key-value using with array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array and it has lots of dictionary's keys it comes from API. My array as follows

Dictionary keys array :

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"01", @"02", @"03"];
```

Dictionary with key-value pairs

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"01": @"Hero", @"02" : @"Enemy", @"03" : @"Boss"};
```

Basically i want to match array values corresponding to dictonary keys without using array. I found a solition about that but I don't want to use for-loop for every cell(I have a lots of cell). My solution is like that

```
for(NSString *item in arr) {
        [convertedArr addObject:[dic valueForKey:item]];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [convertedArr componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```

Asumme have an array like this (1,2,3) and dictionary looks like {1 = "a", 2 = "b", 3 = "c"} I just want to give an array and it should return dictionary values like this ("a","b","c")

Anybody should give me better approach without using array? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to find the values in the dictionary that match an array of keys?

Comment: add what output you want?

Comment: Is it *performance* that you care about or do you want to write *less code*? Do you want to get rid of the *array* or of the *for loop*? Both is possible, but an answer depends on what your objective is.

Comment: @DanielGalasko yes obviously. Assume we have an array it holds three keys (01,02,03) and dictionary keys corresponds to (01 = "a", 02 = "b", 03 = "c") I want to get out like this (a,b,c). I hope tell my problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your for-loop by

```
NSArray *convertedArr = [dic objectsForKeys:arr notFoundMarker:@""];
```

which is at least *less code*. (The `notFoundMarker:` is added for all keys
in the array which are not present in the dictionary. Your code would crash
in that situation.)

It might perform slightly better because it is a library
function. But I doubt that the difference is big, because in any case a dictionary
loopup is required for all keys in `arr`.

Comment: @kayzersoze: May I ask why you "unaccepted" the answer? Please let me know if there is any problem with it.